# Pandas with MatplotLib: plotting regression line with log-x scale

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

The issue is this one:

I'm trying to plot a lineal regression line over a scatter plot, from two Pandas Series obtained from a Panda DataFrame. Each one of these Series represents a column of the DataFrame. Here, the 'X' axis of my scatter plot is represented in a logarithmic scale.

I've looked for a similar issue here:
[Plotting regression line with log y scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71201183/plotting-regression-line-with-log-y-scale)

However, despite having consulted that post, I couldn't achieve to get the result I want to, since in this case, the axis represented with a log scale is 'X' instead of 'Y', the arguments passed to the plot function are Pandas Series instead of NumPy arrays, and finally, I'm using figure and axes unpacked from the subplot function instead of using directly the plot function (this is: "ax.scatter..." instead of "plt.scatter...")

So then, here's my code and my result until now ("municipios" is my DataFrame):
[image: scatter]

Although I've tried a lot of things based on the mentioned post, I'm always getting an unexpected and wrong result, which consists of a line plotted with lots of irregular segments.

Does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong or what should I do?

Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I could achieve this using Seaborn, like this ('municipios' is my whole Pandas DataFrame):

```
x=np.log(municipios['DENSIDAD_HABITACIONAL'])
y=municipios['PORCENTAJE_NBI']

s=sns.regplot(x=x, y=y,fit_reg=True)
s.figure.set_size_inches(18.5, 10.5)

sns.despine()
```

And also:

```
x=np.log(municipios['POBLACION'])
y=np.log(municipios['SUPERFICIE'])

s=sns.regplot(x=x, y=y,fit_reg=True)
s.figure.set_size_inches(18.5, 10.5)

sns.despine()
```